# django - selecting extra data on many to many relation matching

Tags: django, orm, django-models

I have  these two models

```
class SubGroupEvent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('subscription', 'group', 'event')
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, null=True, blank=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AbstractGroup)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

and

```
class Events
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

To get all the events in a group id I use

```
events = events.filter(subgroupevent__group_id=groupID)
```

But I need to be able to get the `subscription` WHERE subgroupevent__group_id=groupID along with the event data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subgroupevent_list = SubGroupEvent.objects.filter(group_id=groupID)

for subgroupevent in subgroupevent_list:
    event = subgroupevent.event
```

Comment: would it make sense to do `SubGroupEvent.objects.select_related('event').filter(group_id=groupID)`?

Answer (score 0):

## Filtering related models:

Try standard [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), and if you stuck try [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). But note not every sql query could be done using ORM, there may be cases when you need to fall back to [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), but even then you could map the fields from raw sql to your model fields(this feature is as actually very cool one).

## Retriving related models

To retrive objects with single query you may find useful [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and
[prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)